# Syntax to monkey patch a class in python

Tags: python, syntax, monkeypatching, language-enhancement

Is there any reason why this syntax wouldn't be possible?

```
def myclass.method(self):
    pass
```

Instead, python currently uses assignment, such as:

```
def f(self):
    pass
myclass.method = f
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that the grammar doesn't define it? Are you looking for a reason *why* Python doesn't support it?

Comment: Near duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39871227/1126841, which confirms that this is invalid syntax without providing a rationale.

Comment: Here's a [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-ideas/8rxVLGryXrg) from the python-ideas mailing list discussing the idea.

Comment: This doesn't provide anywhere near enough benefit to justify its addition.

Comment: (Plenty of syntax is *possible*. That doesn't mean it's *worthwhile*.)